# Difficult on integration the normalization of a piecewise function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, piecewise

I have a little problem; I have defined the following Piecewise-function in the variables {x,L,w}:

```
f[x_, L_, w_] := Piecewise[{{x w (L - x), 0 <= x <= L}}];
```

Then I have defined the normalization of this function:

```
norm[L_, w_] := Integrate[f[x, L, w]^2, {x, 0, L},Assumptions -> (L > 0) \[And] (w > 0) \[And] (L >= x >= 0)];
```

(I have tried different forms of 'Assumptions' but the following problem persists).
Then I defined the normalized function:

```
fnorm[x_, L_, w_] := f[x, L, w]/Sqrt[norm[L, w]];
```

When I tried to plot the previous normalized function, for some numerical values of variables {L,w}, many problems appears:

```
Plot[fnorm[x, 1, 1], {x, 0, 1}];
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.0000204286,0,1}.
NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.000020428571428571424` cannot be used as an iterator.
NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.000020428571428571424` cannot be used as an iterator.
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.0204286,0,1}.
NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.02042859183673469` cannot be used as an iterator.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::itraw will be suppressed during this calculation.
Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.0408368,0,1}.
General::stop: Further output of Integrate::ilim will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Obviously the plot of the normalized function dosen't appeare. The plot,for a range of numerical value for {L,w}, of the normalization, appears:

```
Plot3D[norm[L, w], {L, 0.5, 1}, {w, 0.5, 1}]
```

The previos plot appears without problems.

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Comment: Plot set x equal to a value, then calls fnorm[].  Try `Evaluate[fnorm[x, 1, 1]]`. — Somewhere on site this question is already answered in full.  I’ll try to find it.

Comment: E.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255208/4999, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124706/4999, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46385/4999

Comment: One could also use `=` instead of `:=` in defining `norm[]`, since the symbolic integral can be done: `norm[L_, w_] = Integrate[..]`. If you want to keep `:=`, then best practice would be to localize `x`: `norm[L_, w_] := Module[{x}, Integrate[..]]`. The use of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) means the integral is recalculated every time `norm[]` is called, which would make the code quite slow probably.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your functions by using different argument names:

```
f[x_, L_, w_] := (Print["x=", x]; 
  Piecewise[{{x w (L - x), 0 <= x <= L}}]); 
norm[L_, w_] := 
 Integrate[f[x1, L, w]^2, {x1, 0, L}, 
  Assumptions -> (L > 0) \[And] (w > 0) \[And] (L >= x >= 0)];
fnorm[x2_, L_, w_] := f[x2, L, w]/Sqrt[norm[L, w]];
```

Now, if we run this:

```
Plot[fnorm[x3, 1, 1], {x3, 0, 1}]
```

You get the output:

[image]
....

You see that Integrate and Plot call their functions with symbolic arguments. This is done to eventually simplify the expressions. But in your case "f" delivers not a number as result if called with a symbolic argument. Therefore, ensure that "f" is only called on numeric arguments by:

```
Clear[f, norm, fnorm]
f[x_?NumericQ, L_, w_] := Piecewise[{{x w (L - x), 0 <= x <= L}}]; 
norm[L_, w_] := 
 Integrate[f[x1, L, w]^2, {x1, 0, L}, 
  Assumptions -> (L > 0) \[And] (w > 0) \[And] (L >= x >= 0)];
fnorm[x2_, L_, w_] := f[x2, L, w]/Sqrt[norm[L, w]];
Plot[fnorm[x3, 1, 1], {x3, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works perfectly now.